# Set screen resolution to 1680 x 1050 on a VGA monitor

Tags: multiple-monitors, resolution, display-settings

I changed my screen resolution on my monitor to 1920 x 1080.

And got a message:

```
Input signal out of range 

Please change to 1680 x 1050 @60hz
```

However, this option is not availiable on the screen resolution slider in control panel.

Is there another way to select this resolution ?

[image]

My other monitors are set at 1400 x 900, but when I set monitor 3 at these settings everything seems zoomed in and chunky, it does not match.

For example, I can see less rows of an excel workbook on monitor 3 compared to monitor 1 and 2.

I am using Windows 7.

Comment: What make and model is your graphics card? Ultimately, it’s the deciding factor concerning available resolutions

Comment: What's the native resolution on the VGA monitor?  What's the max VGA resolution for the graphics card?

Comment: @fixer1234 I'm not sure how I find this out will look into it now, the other monitors can select 1680 x 1050 though.

Comment: The information is generally in the specs for the monitor and graphics card (or for the computer if that's the original graphics).  If you no longer have the info and can't find it online, add the model info to the question.  What you describe is typical if you're trying to exceed the monitor's native resolution or the max VGA output for the graphics card.  Roughly 1600x1200 is a common VGA output max, and VGA monitors usually don't go much higher, so you could be bumping up against hard limits.  Are the other monitors identical and connected via VGA?  Do you have 3 VGA outputs?

Comment: The monitor spec can be read via software that displays the EDID from it.  See https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/114359/how-to-get-edid-for-a-single-monitor.  This thread discusses finding the max for the graphics card: https://superuser.com/questions/361744/where-can-one-find-quickly-what-is-the-maximum-resolution-that-a-graphics-card-s.  However, the max output for the port may be less than that for a chipset embedded on the motherboard.

Answer (score 0):

To find more resolution setting, click on **Advanced Settings/ Adapter/ List All Modes**

There you can select your preferred resolution and refresh rate.

Comment: This also does not give 1680 x 1050 as an option

Comment: You could also try a third-party software called [CRU](https://www.monitortests.com/forum/Thread-Custom-Resolution-Utility-CRU)

Comment: Update this to include that the graphics card controls what resolution and framerates it can provide, not the monitor (hence why one can set a resolution/framerate too high and the monitor will displays "out of range"). If the graphics card doesn't support your desired resolution then either change the monitor or change the graphics card.